# How to exclude method in class from scoverage report?

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, code-coverage, scoverage

I have few methods in my scala play framework application that I want to be excluded from scoverage report. Is there any way to achieve this? May be similar to using `@Generated` annotations for methods to be excluded as for Jacoco 0.8.2 release.
Example:

```
class TestClass {
    @Generated
    def methodN = {} 
}
```

Or may be use something like `excludeMethods += "TestClass.methodN, TestClass.methodX"` in **build.sbt** file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs](https://github.com/scoverage/scalac-scoverage-plugin#how-to-use) I'd say that without changing the source code you can exclude only class/package/file from your build tool

```
// examples of scalac options from the docs
// add as e.g. scalacOptions += "-P:scoverage:..." if you are using sbt

-P:scoverage:excludedPackages:.*\.utils\..*;.*\.SomeClass;org\.apache\..*

-P:scoverage:excludedFiles:.*\/two\/GoodCoverage;.*\/three\/.*
```

but if you can modify the source code you can exclude whatever you want by putting the right comments around it

```
// $COVERAGE-OFF$
def methodIWantToIgnore = 2 + 2
// $COVERAGE-ON$
```

If it's the code you written yourself I would use comments, and if it was something spit by the codegen I would suggest the compiler options (scoverage works as a compiler plugin, slightly changing emitted bytecode).